# winapi to read or copy NTUSER.DAT (locked file)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am trying to load `NTUSER.DAT` of logged-in local user in registry hive to read their keys from my program running as admin (it has got `SeDebugPrivilege`, `SeBackupPrivilege`, etc).

It works when the user is logged-out, and doesn't work when they are logged-in.

The error is:

> Error: (32) The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

So, is there any Win32 API, or another way, I can copy `NTUSER.DAT` or read it without relying on a third-party library? I need to do this when they are logged-in.

Shadow Volume Copy copies the whole drive, hence it isn't feasible. Maybe it is possible to unmount their registry hive and then load it using `RegLoadKeyA()` or something?

Comment: The kernel always has an open handle to this file, which causes your attempts to fail. From kernelmode you can use `IoCreateFileEx` with `IO_IGNORE_SHARE_ACCESS_CHECK` flag. It is also possible to use `ZwDuplicateObject` with the existing handle value to get access.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround,
when the user is logged-off you can load NTUSER.DAT of that user in registry, then read key.
if the user is logged-in, you can read their keys from HKU/user-sid